# Showing $D^{-1/2}[D^{-1/2}t^2]=t^3/3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble showing this using gamma functions, it doesn't seem to work out.  I'm trying to use the fact that

$D^{-1/2}(f(t))=1/\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^t{(t-T)^{-1/2}f(T)dT}$

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you use that $D^m [D^n f(t)] = D^{m+n}\; f(t)$?

Comment: @dalastboss I'm not sure honestly I'll check it out see if it works

Comment: By the way what course is this?

Comment: @science ordinary differential equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

$$D^{-1/2}t^2 = \pi^{-1/2}\int_0^t (t - u)^{-1/2}u^2\, du = \pi^{-1/2}t^{5/2}\int_0^1 (1 - v)^{-1/2}v^2\, dv,$$

using the substitution $u = tv$. Now

$$\pi^{-1/2}\int_0^1 (1 - v)^{-1/2}v^2\, dv = \pi^{-1/2}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(7/2)} = \frac{2}{\Gamma(7/2)},$$

Thus

$$D^{-1/2}[D^{-1/2}t^2] = \frac{2}{\Gamma(7/2)}D^{-1/2}(t^{5/2}).\tag{1}$$

Since

$$D^{-1/2}(t^{5/2}) = \pi^{-1/2}\int_0^t (t - u)^{-1/2}u^{5/2}\, du = \pi^{-1/2}t^{3}\int_0^1 (1 - t)^{-1/2}u^{5/2}\, du,$$

and

$$\pi^{-1/2}\int_0^1 (1 - u)^{-1/2}u^{5/2}\, du = \pi^{-1/2}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(7/2)}{\Gamma(4)} = \frac{\Gamma(7/2)}{6},$$

we have

$$D^{-1/2}(t^{5/2}) = \frac{t^3\Gamma(7/2)}{6}. \tag{2}$$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$, $D^{-1/2}[D^{-1/2}t^2] = t^3/3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula for a monomial

> $$ D^{-n} x^{m} = \frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+n+1)} x^{m+n} $$

which comes from the definition you are using for fractional derivative. In your case $n=1/2$ and you need to apply it twice.

**Note:**

> $$ D^{-n}t^m = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^t{(t-y)^{n-1}y^m dy} = \frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+n+1)} x^{m+n}. $$

You can use the beta function to evaluate the above integral.